# 802.11 frame transmission route and used addresses

Tags: frame, packet, wifi

I have a WiFi System that consists of two Access Points **AP1** and **AP2** with the addresses **MAC_AP1** and **MAC_AP2**.

There are two stations in the BSS of **AP1**, **STA1** and **STA2** with the addresses **MAC_STA1** and **MAC_STA2**.

There is one station in the BSS of **AP2**, **STA3** with the adress **MAC_STA3**.

Also there is a **server** on the distribution system with the adress **MAC_SERVER**.

**Here is a drawing**

[image]]

**Question 1:** If STA1 sends a frame to STA2, which which way does it go? 
My guess is that it is like the purple Arrows shows. STA1 sends it to AP1 and AP1 to STA2.

**Question 2:** Which addresses are necessary on the wireless interface and why?

My thoughts so far, assuming I got the path right:

- DA Field = MAC_STA2
- SA Field = MAC_STA1
- RA Field = MAC_AP1
- TA Field = MAC_STA1

So I would need the addresses of MAC_STA1, MAC_STA2, and MAC_AP1 correct?

**Question 3:** Same as above, but this time the frame is sent from the Server to STA3.

- DA Field = MAC_STA3
- SA Field = MAC_SERVER
- RA Field = MAC_AP2
- TA Field = MAC_SERVER

So I would need the addresses of MAC_STA3, MAC_SERVER, and MAC_AP2 correct?

**Question 3.1:** Name all used addresses on the distribution system.
I would give the same answer as to the previous question, which is probably wrong.

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: What is this - homework? Interview question?

Comment: a training question to prepare for an exam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Your are right

Question 2 & 3:

Addressing in 80211 will not contain all 4 addresses always. Most of the cases it contains only 3. Below are the corresponding addresses:

Question 2: Addr1 = MAC_AP1; Addr2 = MAC_STA1; Addr3 = MAC_STA2

Question 3:

Here the SERVER sends the packet to AP2 over Ethernet as an Ethernet frame. AP2 in turn will extract layer 3 data (IP) from Ethernet frame and encapsulate it inside 80211 header. The address fields in this header are as below:

Addr1 = MAC_STA3; Addr2 = MAC_AP2; Addr3 = MAC_SERVER